# javascript Trumbowyg wysiwyg editor not show active button?

Tags: javascript, wysiwyg, text-editor, rich-text-editor, trumbowyg

javascript `Trumbowyg wysiwyg` editor `not show active` button ?

With this code, when fill some char into editor and select all text and then press `B` button. All text will bold but why `B` button not show active.

REMARK : italic button `[I]` not show active too

How can i do ?

http://plnkr.co/edit/hhlL0uPNJr16osyKzKRw?p=preview
.

.

.

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Alex-D/Trumbowyg/v2.4.1/dist/trumbowyg.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.rawgit.com/Alex-D/Trumbowyg/v2.4.1/dist/ui/trumbowyg.min.css">

    <div id="main" role="main">
        <div id="editor">
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        /** Default editor configuration **/
        $('#editor').trumbowyg(
            {
                btns: [
                    ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strikethrough']
                ]
            }
        );
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `btn` names used in JavaScript have developer proper names. For this purpose you must use script like this:

```
btns: ['strong', 'em', 'del']
```